# Why can't I use a char as a parameter of a function?

Tags: c, char

I have the following function on my code:

```
int leepos(char *entrada, char elem)
```

Which is being called the following way:

```
leepos(entrada,'y');
```

For me it looks ok, but I get the following error: [Error] conflicting types for 'leepos'

Oddly enough, I can make my function work with these little modifications:

Defining the function as:

```
int leepos(char *entrada, char* elem)
```

And calling it with:

```
leepos(entrada,"y");
```

I can make it work properly once I change the logic that treated the char to treat strings.

It looks like the error is then in using char as a parameter, although it looks quite strange. Any idea of why this may happen?

I'm giving the code that shows the error is on using char:

```
int main()
{
  leepos("hi",'y');
  leepos2("hi","y");
}

int leepos(char *entrada, char elem)
{
  return 0;
}

int leepos2(char *entrada, char* elem)
{
  return 0;
}
```

The program works nice if I delete the line leepos("hi",'y');, the error is still the same as the one shown, so I think this makes clear the error has to be there.

Comment: The error may not be where you think it is. Please provide a [mcve] that shows the problem so that a definitive answer can be given.

Comment: In answer to the question in your title: because you're doing something wrong. The rest of us can do it. Had you shown sufficient code, you'd have an answer already. ;shrugs:

Comment: maybe there is `int leepos(char *entrada, char* elem);` somewhere in your header file.

Comment: I'm not even using a custom header file.

Comment: You need to declare the functions *before* calling them. Otherwise the compiler will make some assumptions (e.g. that the parameters are integers).

Comment: Nice, that was the answer, anyway I wonder why it only happens only with the function that uses char as parameter and not the other, but well it's solved.

Comment: @user2638180 This is why you should use a header file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to prototype the function before calling it:

```
int leepos(char *entrada, char elem);

int main()
{
    leepos("hi",'y');
}

int leepos(char *entrada, char elem)
{
    return 0;
}
```

Another way is to put the whole function body before `main` (the first line serves as a prototype too).

Since C99 it is not allowed at all to call a function that has not been declared. The error you saw about conflicting types, and the differing behaviour of `leepos2`, comes from using the C89 rules for how function calls to undeclared functions behave.